# Django Pillow Install Works for Migrate, But Not Run

Tags: python, django, pycharm, python-imaging-library

When running mange makemigrations, I got an error that said I needed to install Pillow because I was using an ImageField. I ran the following on MacOS:

> python3 -m pip install pillow
>   Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
>   Collecting pillow
>     Downloading Pillow-7.0.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (3.9 MB)
>        |████████████████████████████████| 3.9 MB 2.1 MB/s
>   Installing collected packages: pillow
>   Successfully installed pillow-7.0.0

When I ran the checkmigrations again, it didn't complain and the migrate worked as well. In my models.py file, I didn't receive any errors (from PyCharm) for the follow import:

```
from PIL import Image
```

I read I had to use this command in place of Pillow. Using Pillow gets flagged as not found.

When I ran the run command in PyCharm, I get the error:

> ERRORS:
>   base.Team.profile_image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
>       HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".

When I check the Project Interpreter in PyCharm, it shows Pillow as a package at the latest version.

I've used home-brew to install the latest version of Python3. There is also the outdated MacOS version. Could Pillow it be installed in the wrong location? How could I tell?

Another odd thing is that I can only run migrations from within PyCharm. From the shell in the project directory I get:

> python3 -m manage.py checkmigrations
>   /usr/local/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'manage.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: **path** attribute not found on 'manage' while trying to find 'manage.py')

It works fine when I run it within PyCharm

### Fix

Yes I have pipenv installed, but it wasn't running a shell. I was thinking it was more link rbenv, which I've used quite a bit. This is my first django project.

I started with:

> merrittsecurity python3 -m pipenv shell

My prompt changed to:

> (merrittsecurity) ➜  merrittsecurity

I'm using iTerm2, zshrc, and oh my ZSH. I'm guessing oh my ZSH is adding it. Nice feature.

Because of the line wrap on my browser, I was sure if it was djangopillow or two words. I chose the former because it would error out if it wasn't the correct one. It did and I entered:

> (merrittsecurity) ➜  merrittsecurity pipenv install django pillow

That worked, but gave errors saying it could find djangopillow. I found it in the pip file and deleted it. Sometimes wrong choices, leave detritus. When I ran the pillow install again, it finished without error.

Comment: Sounds like pillow isn't in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any virtual environment? If not, you definitely should be. I'd recommend pipenv. Install it, then run `pipenv shell` in your project folder, then run `pipenv install django pillow`. After it's installed, run `pip freeze` and see if pillow is on the list.